# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin (default-compile) on project: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have done all the steps provided in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_environment_setup.htm

Apache Maven and Apache tomcat both are ready. I also set the environments. I created Maven project in Eclipse, it gives Build Failure while I run this using Maven build.

It gives this error

> "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project Hello2: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40..\lib\tools.jar"

What should I do?

Comment: Have you checked if you have java_home defined in your environment variables ?

Comment: Yes environment variable is defined in system path.

Comment: It looks like you have defined the JAVA_HOME pointing to JRE instead of JDK

Comment: I have directly set both JRE and JDK in system path.

Comment: @khmarbaise You are right. It worked after I changed `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to set eclipse's default installed "jre" to a jdk.  Eclipse Window Menu => Preferences => enter search string "jre" in left navigation pane => click on "Installed JREs" in left navigation pane => Click Add and browse to your JDK. => click the check box next to the JDK to make it default.

You may need to download and install the java jdk if you don't already have it.

Also ensure the eclipse run configuration is set to use the default jdk you set up:  Run Menu => Run Configurations => Select the run config for your project (Maven Build) => Click JRE tab => Under Runtime JRE select "workspace default".

Comment: @abdul There is an upvote and Accept Answer option. Please do that as well

Comment: I have another question. i have to Deploy Application on Apache Tomcat Server. Right click on Server -> Add and Remove ->. but i get this message "there are no resources that can be added or removed from server"

Comment: One question, you got answer. Please accept his answer and upvote. If that's a new question, please post that as new

Comment: Also, Apache Tomcat is not a sever, it's just a container

Comment: Ok Sir, but I can't upvote because of my reputation less than 15.

Comment: I had to create an environment variable JAVA_HOME within eclipse and point that to JDK7, then it started working

Comment: how about in Netbeas, any idea?

Comment: I just don't get the fact that eclipse saying to set installed jre when in fact it is the jdk that should be pointed into execution environment.but thanks this solves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I delete my .m2 local  local repository and re-run it. It works.

Comment: I would be careful doing that. This removes all your local maven dependency libraries. You will likely need to reinstall on every project after doing this. I also think it may have been coincidence that this solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, at that time, my .m2 was just installed, so I deleted it and it didn't affect any of the environment, but what you said is really helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check the JAVA version, It should be same across all the places. 
See screenshots.

1. pom.xml 
   [image]
2. JAVA build path
   [image]
3. JAVA compiler
   [image]

Note: To see configuration window for 2 and 3... right click on the project and click properties

Answer (score 0):

Delete repository from `.m2 -> repository` and then right click on the project `Run as... -> Maven install`.

After that, again right click on the project `Maven -> Update project -> Check Update of Snapshots` and click on the `Ok` option.

Answer (score -1):

I am using windows OS with JDK 1.9 in eclipse Oxygen. I faced this issue while compiling the project with JDK 1.9 while using maven and I solved by changing `mvn.cmd` file present in `C:\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin`.

**Before:**

```
set "JAVACMD=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin\java.exe"
```

**After:**

```
set "JAVACMD=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe"
```

Also, make sure the compiler you use to build the project is correctly configured in IDE you use.

Comment: The question above indicates that JDK 8 is already being used (see path references after "tools.jar not found". So, the answer above suggesting a change from JDK 9 to JDK 8 likely will not solve the problem.

Comment: That's JRE path mentioned in path references. I mentioned to provide JDK path properly. Not finding tools jar might be a reason of not setting the JDK(till 1.8) path properly or not setting JAVA_HOME value properly. And my answer is providing the solution to one of the possible cause to the issue which I faced.