# Can't run maven install on eclipse anymore (tools.jar not found)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working on ubuntu 16.04 and I have an eclipse project I cant compile anymore. Everytime I try I have this error :

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5:compile (default-compile) on project TwavoxManager: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
```

I first I could compile it without any problems, but I had to reinstall java on my system (openJDK8).

I tried the solution from this link [Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin (default-compile) on project: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700576/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-compiler-plugin-default-c/29700727)

But the thing is openJDK8 has JDK + JRE right ? 
I am completely lost here

EDIT : added pom.xml :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>cineapps</groupId>
  <artifactId>TwavoxManager</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>TwavoxManager</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- COMPILER -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- RESOURCES -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- SHADE -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>TwavoxManager-${project.version}-min</finalName>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>cineapps.TwavoxManager.app.App</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/res</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.54</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.miglayout/miglayout-swing -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
    <artifactId>miglayout-swing</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <version>1.0</version>
</project>
```

EDIT : usefull screens :

[image]

Comment: Share your pom.xml please and set the project specific JRE to your project

Comment: @Zia added pom.xml

Comment: could you please  modify the plugin entry in your pom,<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

Comment: I have this error now : [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project TwavoxManager: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Comment: Right click on your project, Build Path->Configure Build Path. Select "JRE System Library" in the right options select edit and then configure your JDK

Comment: Is the file mentioned `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/tools.jar` present? It looks like you might be using a JRE instead of JDK (yes, I'm aware that the name says JDK; just want to make sure).

Comment: @Andrei no the tools.jar is not present, but before uninstalling/reinstalling java, i didn't have to add it

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you need to add it manually.
I think this is a case of having JRE instead of JDK, OR referencing wrong path in JAVA_HOME environment variable. Can you check these two items?

Comment: check comments on the answer bellow for java_home

Comment: I did; I'm pretty sure at this point that the cause is that you installed JRE instead of JDK (only JDK has `tools.jar` in it). List the contents of your `JAVA_HOME` and see there is no JDK folder present, only JRE.

Comment: Idd i dont have JDK folder only JRE, but isn't openJDK8 a JDK+JRE ??? Im confused

Comment: I think the name is confusing. I think "OpenJdk" is the brand, in the same way "Pepsi" is a brand. But just like other distributions of java, it comes in a JRE version and in a JDK version (don't think it's feasible to change the name to OpenJre just to clarify the confusion), EVEN THOUGH it does contain the name "jdk" in it.

Comment: Check this link for example: http://openjdk.java.net/install/
It says:
_The openjdk-8-jre package contains just the Java Runtime Environment. If you want to develop Java programs then please install the openjdk-8-jdk package._

This should clear it up...

Comment: yeah i just checked it and idd it was that, i had openjdk-jre , damn dummy thx u sir !

Answer (score 1):

Update your plugin entry in pom.xml,

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and Configure the project JDK,

Right click on your project, Build Path->Configure Build Path. Select "JRE System Library" in the right options select edit and then configure your JDK

Comment: It didn't work, i still have same error, i provided a screen of my JRE system LIbrary in my original post

Comment: Might be usefull, I ran echo£ $JAVA_HOME in the terminal and got this : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/

Comment: Edit that JRE and looked in the installed JRE,point it to JDK you mentioned " /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/"

Comment: there is no jdk folder in jre but i have java/bin and java/jre/bin