# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project

Tags: java, maven

I had a java project which I reconfigured to a Maven project. After reconfiguring and adding most of the dependencies required, I get the following error in console when I run `mvn install` command. I tried the solution mentioned here on [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700576/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-compiler-plugin-default-c), but it doesnt help

Following are the console logs:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building FlockHydraAutomation 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ FlockHydraAutomation ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ FlockHydraAutomation ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 15 source files to C:\Maven\FlockHydra-Automation\FlockHydraAutomation\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.249 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-23T13:44:15+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project FlockHydraAutomation: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

POM File:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.Flock</groupId>
    <artifactId>FlockHydraAutomation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>FlockHydraAutomation</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>flockWebclient</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Attached is the screenshot of the Java Compiler:
[Java Compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqlGk.png)

Comment: Take a look at `mvn -version` anc check for your java version and java home there.

Comment: First you are using a JRE instead of JDK which is configured via environment variable. Furthermore you should follow the conventions in Maven and do not change configuration like setting the sourceDirectory and the resources. Remove those parts...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your comment on the previous answer looks like you are indeed pointing to a JDK. 
So now can you try this, Open Eclipse and goto Windows-> preferences -> Java -> installed JREs, and check if you are pointing to a JRE. If yes, change the path to your JDK and try to run a Maven build again. Hopefully this helps resolve the issue.

Comment: how to change path to jdk?

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure, your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable points to a JDK (not a JRE), as the error mentions.

> [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Execute `mvn -version`. The output will show, what directory JAVA_HOME point to. Then make sure, this is a JDK by setting the `JAVA_HOME` variable to a JDK path.

Comment: My JAVA_HOME points to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

but when i do mvn -version it points to a JRE

Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, followed the recommendations stated above, but the issued persist.

below was my pom.xml

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>  
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration> 
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <fork>true</fork>
     <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\javac</executable>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>tomcat-run</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <attachartifactclassifier>exec-war</attachartifactclassifier>
                    <attachartifactclassifiertype>jar</attachartifactclassifiertype>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
                <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>spring-boot:run</goal>
      </goals>

    </plugin>

</plugins>
```

To fix the issue, do use this pom.xml

```
<build>
<plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

</plugins>
```

Attached is the snapshot of my IDE .

[image snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3hEu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error and it turned out to be an issue with the .classpath file for me:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

The attribute pointing to the "/WEB-INF/lib" folder was missing in my case.